# Invertibility of Random Fourier Features

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction, kernel-trick, compression, random-projection

Is it possible to approximately reconstruct a point $ \mathbf{x} $ in a vector space (say $\mathbb{R}^n $) given it's randomized feature map $ z(\cdot) $ and respective projection $ z(\mathbf{x})$ (in a lower dimensional vector space, say $ \mathbb{R}^m $, $ m < n $)? Which of the random projections methods (e.g. Johnson-Lindenstrauss transform) allow efficient methods for recovering the original high dimensional points?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what is the connection between a randomized feature map and Fourier features? Are you talking about a feature map such as the Fourier transform? Also the Fourier transform is a deterministic map...so still confused.

Comment: You might want to look into the compressive sensing literature

Comment: compressive sensing is quite broad area... do you have any concrete references therein?

Comment: I'm talking about random low-dimensional feature maps, like the Rahimi-Recht one, which uses the Fourier transform of a kernel (⋅,⋅) https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~brecht/papers/07.rah.rec.nips.pdf